# Interpolation between values in two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists. I want to interpolate between each element of the two lists.

```
Interpolation_greater_values = [2.7577, 147.1441, 292.4872, 512.2606, 840.8513, 1335.3837, 1462.9142]
Interpolation_small_values = [0.0000, 145.9340, 291.3053, 511.1912, 839.7539, 1333.8079, 1461.3383]
```

e.g. I want to interpolate between `2.7577` and `0.0000`, `147.1441` and `145.9340`, and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: scipy and numpy have good tools to use for this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: And when you say "interpolate", then you mean "I want to take the pairwise average between elements in two lists", don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1 = [2.7577, 147.1441, 292.4872, 512.2606, 840.8513, 1335.3837, 1462.9142]
l2 = [0.0000, 145.9340, 291.3053, 511.1912, 839.7539, 1333.8079, 1461.3383]

interp = [(i1 + i2)/2.0 for i1, i2 in zip(l1, l2)]

>>> interp
[1.37885, 146.53905, 291.89625, 511.72589999999997, 840.3026, 1334.5958, 1462.1262499999998]
```

I would also suggest looking into numpy for linear algebra, these types of operations are very fast and well supported.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l1 = np.array([2.7577, 147.1441, 292.4872, 512.2606, 840.8513, 1335.3837, 1462.9142])
>>> l2 = np.array([0.0000, 145.9340, 291.3053, 511.1912, 839.7539, 1333.8079, 1461.3383])
>>> (l1 + l2) / 2.0
array([1.37885000e+00, 1.46539050e+02, 2.91896250e+02, 5.11725900e+02, 8.40302600e+02, 1.33459580e+03, 1.46212625e+03])
```

Comment: @AmeyaKulkarni: if this answers your question, please accept it (by clicking on the check mark to the left).